# Communication between Activity and Fragment in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

As google announced the Kotlin as an official language for Android development, I am trying to build an app using Kotlin.

**Question: How can I communicate between activity and fragment using Kotlin?**

Thanks!.

Comment: Kotlin has nothing to do with this question, you can use the same methods as you'd use in Java. Here's something from the official dev site, for example: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: there's no real difference other than different language (java vs kotlin)

Comment: I just want to know the syntax that how can I implement the interface in activity as we do in Java.

Comment: Try the official Kotlin docs for that: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/interfaces.html

Comment: Ok Thanks @zsmb13

Answer (score 2):

As @SergiyKorotun suggested. Kotlin is just a language it doesn't change the fundamentals of Android.
You should take a look at [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html) added by Android Team which can help you achieve communication between `Activity` and `Fragment`.

I even made a sample application to help understand `ViewModel` and `LiveData`. The application is written in Kotlin.
[Android Architecture News App Sample](https://github.com/AkshayChordiya/android-arch-news-sample)

Comment: I just wanted to know the syntax what we do in Java. Thanks for your answer and for this sample

Comment: Man, I wish that ViewModel was out of alpha state. Looks promising

Comment: It is now out of alpha state. Check out at developer.android.com/arch

Answer (score 1):

As the same as in Java. Kotlin is just a language. For communication you can use some interface or [SharedViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html#sharing_data_between_fragments) like in new architecture components

Comment: Can you give a syntax demo?, I know the communication in Java but not in Kotlin.

Comment: @AmirRaza, just copy and paste your java code to kotlin's file and the android studio will convert the code for you

Answer (score 0):

A Fragment and a activity can communicate through global variables. But I recommend them communicating through a shared View Object value, so other fragments may modify it. In Kotlin you may use

```
ExampleFrament.newInstance().view
```

inside the scope of the `MainActivity()` so other helper functions may access that view.